# Using values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP frameworks and am stuck on a problem where I am trying to put the values of an array into a site url in Codeigniter. I am querying a database and getting the results back no problem. I am trying to use each result to create links using site urls.

Here is what I have at the so far

```
  if (is_array($results))
   {

    if( !empty($results) ) 
    {  
      foreach($results as $row) 
         {
          $venue_name = $row->venue_name;
          $venue_town = $row->venue_town;
          $venue_county = $row->venue_county;

          echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">'; 

          echo '<tr>';

          echo '<h4>';
          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_round.'</td>'."</br></br>";

          echo '<td >'.'<img src="'."$row->team_logo".'">   '.$row->fixture_text.'    <img src="'."$row->team_logo_2".'"> '.'</td>'."</br></br>";
             echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_comp.'</td>'."</br>";
             echo '</h4>';
             echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_time.' '.$row->fixture_date.'</td>'."</br></br>";
             echo '<td>'.$row->venue_name.',  '.$row->venue_town.'</td>'."</br></br>";

             echo '</tr>';
         }
       }

      else echo "Not Array";

    }
```

I am trying to create a link that uses values from the array and concatenates them together to create a link  - I have enabled query strings and am trying to use $_GET to do something like this but I cant get it to work

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/reviews?venue_name=$venue_name&venue_town=$venue_town&venue_county=$venue_county') ?>Link to item</a>
```

This goes to a page but it displays the variable names instead of the value contained within them.

```
Welcome to $venue_name, $venue_town, $venue_county
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works really slick. You will need to load the url helper first:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then you can do this:

```
<?php echo anchor('user/reviews?venue_name='.$venue_name.'&venue_town='.$venue_town.'&venue_county='.$venue_county, 'Link to item', 'title="Link to item"'); ?>
```

Or the traditional way (you do not need to load the helper in this case):

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/reviews?venue_name='.$venue_name.'&venue_town='.$venue_town.'&venue_county='.$venue_county) ?>Link to item</a>
```

[CI URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Ok I think we need to take a step back a bit. Believe it or not, but I think you are trying to do *too* much yourself. Let the framework help you out a little more...

In your project, you should have a view, a controller and a model. It sounds like you have each, and your model is returning results.

Now, in your controller it should look something like this:

```
<?php 
// load venue model
// load review model
// load user model
// load any other helpers

public function index(){
    $venues = [];
    $venues = $this->venue_model->get_all_venues();

    $data[ 'venues' ] = ( $venues ) ? $venues : NULL;
    $this->load->view( 'path-to-your-view', $data );
}


<p>Venues</p>
<?php
if ( $venues )
{
?>
    <table>
    <?php
    foreach($venues as $venue)
    {
    ?>      
        <tr><td><?php echo anchor( 'user/reviews/'.$venue->venue_id, $venue->venue_name); ?></td></tr>
    <?php  
    }
    ?>
    </table>
<?php
}
?>
... rest of your markup here ....
```

Then you will have a route something like (controller names are example):

```
$route['user-reviews/(:num)'] = 'your_controller/get_user_review/$1';
```

Then in the controller, you will have a matching method:

```
<?php
public function get_user_review($userID) {
    $user_reviews = $this->your_model->get_user_reviews('$user_id);
    $data[ 'user_reviews' ] = ( $user_reviews ) ? $user_reviews : NULL;
    $this->load->view( 'path-to-your-view', $user_reviews );
}
```

And finally, your view:

```
<h1>Reviews</h1>
<?php
if($user_reviews) {
    // loop through reviews.
}
else {
?>      
   <p>No reviews found for user.</p>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used your answer and it goes to the page I need which is perfect. This is what I did to it `<a href="<?php echo site_url("user/reviews? venue_name='$venue_name'.venue_town='$venue_town'.venue_county='$venue_county'") ?>Link</a>` I need to take it a step further. I need to somehow use the $_GET method to assign the values because on the  page where the link goes I have the following which displays the values in the variables `echo "Welcome to  ".$_GET['venue_name'].", ". $_GET['venue_town'].", ".$_GET['venue_county'] ;`

Comment: I updated my response - hopefully it will get you rolling in the right direction. It takes a bit to get used to, but once the light bulb goes on it's pretty neat.

Comment: I went back to my code and used your original suggestions and they both work. I particularly like the URL helpers one which is nice and clean. The second one is similar to what I was trying to use but mine was full of quotation marks in the wrong places. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed in your question example code:

The reason you are getting the variable names is because you have the variable (eg: `$venue_name`) enclosed inside **single quotes**.

When using variables inside single quotes, you have to break the variables outside of them.

Another thing I noticed in your example is that the `<a>` tag is not closed properly.
(You might have this fixed in your code?)

You have:

```
...$venue_county) ?>Link to item</a>
```

It should be:

```
                  Notice
                    VV
...$venue_county) ?>">Link to item</a>
```

Try This:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/reviews?venue_name='.$venue_name.'&venue_town='.$venue_town.'&venue_county='.$venue_county) ?>">Link to item</a>
```

Creating a proper link will allow you to pass those variables to the other page where you can use `$_GET` to retrieve those values.

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question - I was missing the closing bracket from the anchor tag I posted - the joys of copy and paste :)